# Unable to format xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, class, oop

OK so i have 2 classes

```
public class PRData
{
    public DateTime PRDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And one is

```
public class MonthData
{
    public string Months { get; set; }
    public List<PRData> PrList { get; set; }
}
```

Now i created an instance of the `MonthData` and `PRData` classes and filled in some data.

```
        PRData pr = new PRData();
        pr.Title = "hello";
        pr.PRDate = DateTime.Now;
        pr.Description = "Hello world";

        List<PRData> prList =new List<PRData>();
        prList.Add(pr);
        prList.Add(pr);

        MonthData mon = new MonthData();
        mon.Months = "feb";
        mon.PrList = prList;
```

Now i'm trying to convert this Object into an xml

```
string xml = Helper.GetXMLFromObject(mon);
```

The xml that i'm receiving is

```
 <MonthData>
  <Months>feb</Months> 
  <PrList>
    <PRData>
      <PRDate>2012-02-01T00:00:00</PRDate> 
      <Title>hello</Title> 
      <Description>Hello world</Description> 
    </PRData>
    <PRData>
      <PRDate>2012-02-01T00:00:00</PRDate> 
      <Title>hello</Title> 
      <Description>Hello world</Description> 
     </PRData>
  </PrList>
</MonthData>
```

Is there any way to remove the `PrList` tag so that the xml looks like

```
 <MonthData>
  <Months>feb</Months> 
  <PRData>
    <PRDate>2012-02-01T00:00:00</PRDate> 
    <Title>hello</Title> 
    <Description>Hello world</Description> 
  </PRData>
  <PRData>
    <PRDate>2012-02-01T00:00:00</PRDate> 
    <Title>hello</Title> 
    <Description>Hello world</Description> 
   </PRData>
</MonthData>
```

The function that i'm using is below to convert object to xml

```
 public static string GetXMLFromObject(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer XmlS = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

            XmlS.Serialize(tw, o);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DataAccessException("Could Not Serialize object : GetXMLFromObject" + " : " + ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

***Note::***
The solution that i'm looking forward to is by making some changes in my classes and not in the function to convert object to xml that i have given above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the `XmlElement` attribute to the `PrList` property:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

...

[XmlElement]
public List<PRData> PrList { get; set; }
```